# window.opener not working in chrome & IE

Tags: javascript, window.opener

I have one child popup.
From this child popup I am sending some values from child popup to textbox of parent page.

javascript is working fine in firefox but not working in chrome & IE

Bellow is the javascript

```
function submitValues(value1,value2)
{
  window.close();
  window.opener.document.getElementById("value1Id").value = value1;
  window.opener.document.getElementById("value2Id").value = value2;
}
```

I am not able to figure out that what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to showModalDialog function. Simply pass window object as an argument.

```
window.showModalDialog(theURL, window);
```

Yo can access the arguments from the modal window using dialogArguments. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533723%28VS.85%29.aspx

```
var openerWindow = window.dialogArguments;
```

Comment: I want to send data from child popup to parent page

Comment: You may modify this. My answer is just to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below function if it works
The window.close will close the window

```
function submitValues(value1,value2)
{

   window.opener.document.getElementById("value1Id").value = value1;
   window.opener.document.getElementById("value2Id").value = value2;
   window.close();
}
```